# Javascript `this` - reference containing object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Javascript and React to build a front end. I am not sure how to reference a method of the containing object:

```
     var RAttribute = React.createClass({

        loadAssignmentsForList: function(elem) {
                //other code
            },

            render: function() {
                    var assignmentsLoading = this.props.assignmentsLoading;
                    var lists = this.props.data.lists.map(function(elem) {
                       return (<li className='list-group-item grey'>
                         <div className='list-group'>
                           <RList key = {elem.name} data={elem}
                              assignmentsLoading={assignmentsLoading}
                              loadAssignmentsForList={this.loadAssignmentsForList(elem)}/>
                       </div>
                      </li>);
                    });
                    //other code
          }
       //other code
     });
```

I am trying to call `loadAssignmentsForList` from within `render` so I am using `this.loadAssignmentsForList(elem)`. However, I get the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadAssignmentsForList' of undefined
```

Comment: Are you transpiling ES6? If so you could use arrow functions. It really depends on your setup

Comment: That should work from the code you provided, must be something we can't see there

Comment: Though it's my understanding that React should auto bind `this` in the `render` method

Comment: Your code works https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/19357/ could you provide more code

Comment: I provided more of the code. The error actually appears within a `map` method.

Comment: @Alexander Nice, now I know how to `React` on jsfiddle, but your example is not exactly the same

Comment: @Juan Mendes example https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/19359/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind `.this` to `.map`, `this` in `.map` does not refer to `RAttribute` object

```
var lists = this.props.data.lists.map(function(elem) {
   // your code             
}.bind(this));
```

or you can set `this` to `.map` through second argument, like this

```
var lists = this.props.data.lists.map(function(elem) {
   // your code             
}, this);
```

also, if you are using `ES6` you can use [arrow functions](http://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/)

```
var lists = this.props.data.lists.map((elem) => {
   // your code             
});
```